# What is the easiest way to upload HTML code in JIRA

Tags: html, jira

I need to upload a HTML code in JIRA but unable to locate the right icon. Any ideas?

I went through the issue details and features but all I find there is icon to attach images. I'm using team-managed project in trial version of Jira.

Comment: Do you meant [this](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JHTML/pages/1482361023/HTML+for+Jira+gadget) or just the [attach file](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver/attaching-files-and-screenshots-to-issues-939937892.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean HTML code that should be the body of the issue, then you should use [REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/9.10.0/) or [Java API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/9.10.0/) and set that you use HTML and not Markup as default formatting is the **Markup**.